# What is this embedded video editor software?

Tags: javascript, video

Hello everyone recently i bumped into this site that had this embedded video editing software [here](https://hylight.tv/#/demo). What library did the guy who made this use or did he make it from scratch?

The thing this guy made looks really cool and i would really love to try and make something like this to so i would love it if the library also had some documentation.

Comment: Why don't you email him? `Any bugs/questions? send a mail to contact@hylight.tv`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @j0 i think that is moslty meant for bugs and it support

Comment: @Rob well the idea is i would like to make a program that uses this software

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS was used to create that webpage/Application according to the BuiltWith Chrome extension. You'd have to contact the creator for more detailed information.